# MySQL server won't install to a new os (Debian, Ubuntu)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, mysql

Today I wanted to install (on a new VPS with new OS) a MySQL server.

I used this command:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client-5.5
```

I tried with Debian 7 (x64 and x86) and Ubuntu 13.04 (x64 and x86).

Every time I got this error message:

```
140223  9:37:33 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_b
uffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the
 full name instead.
140223  9:37:33 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of m
yisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Ple
ase use the full name instead.
140223  9:37:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140223  9:37:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140223  9:37:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140223  9:37:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140223  9:37:33 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140223  9:37:33  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 att
empts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
```

A video in which I'm trying to install Ubuntu: http://youtu.be/nULSfa0xZdU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Disabling via my.cnf

This sounds like your issue, titled: [InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=529).

*excerpt*

> and you find this error somewhere in it:
>
> ```
>     131201 19:22:27 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>     131201 19:22:27  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
>     InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
>     InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
>     InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
>     InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
>     InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
>     131201 19:22:30  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
>     InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
>     131201 19:22:30 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
> ```
>
> then the solution would be to add:
>
> ```
>   innodb_use_native_aio = 0
> ```
>
> to the [mysqld] section of your /etc/my.cnf file.

#### Increasing the aio-max-nr

Also you might be able to increase the kernel setting via:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
1048576
```

Kernel settings such as this can be overridden using the `sysctl` command:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | grep aio
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.aio-nr = 0

$ sysctl -w fs.aio-max-nr=200000
```

Comment: adding innodb_use_native_aio = 0 to the mysqld section worked for me with, didnt have to do anything else

Comment: But raising the `fs.aio-max-nr` setting is actually a better solution, because it allows AIO to keep working. InnoDB uses AIO for a reason, disabling it probably hurts performance.

Comment: Thank you innodb_use_native_aio = 0 helped me solve the problem :)